# Merge two Queues in Java

Tags: java, merge, queue

I have been working on this code to properly merge and print these two queues, but to no avail. If someone could help point me in the right direction or let me know what I am doing wrong, it would be most appreciated.

Node Class

```
public class Node<E> {

    private E element;
    private Node next;

    public Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
        // Do something here
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }
    public void setNextNode(Node<E> next) {
        // Do something here
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node<E> getNextNode() {
        // Replace return null with something useful
        return next;
    }
}
```

LinkedList class

```
public class LinkedListQueue<E> implements Queue<E> {

    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;
    private int size;

    public LinkedListQueue() {    
    }

    public void enqueue(E element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element, null);

        if (size == 0) {
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            tail.setNextNode(newNode);
        }

        tail = newNode;
        size++;
    }

    public E dequeue() {
        if (head != null) {
            E element = head.getElement();
            head = head.getNextNode();
            size--;
            if (size == 0) {
                tail = null;
            }
            return element;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public E first() {
        if (head != null) {
            return head.getElement();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void printList() {
        if (head != null) {
            Node currentNode = head;
            do {
                System.out.println(currentNode.toString());
                currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
            } while (currentNode != null);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Queue Class

```
public interface Queue<E> {

    public void enqueue(E e);

    public E dequeue();

    public E first();

    public int getSize();

    public void printList();

}
```

Main Class

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     LinkedListQueue q1 = new LinkedListQueue();
     q1.enqueue(1);
     q1.enqueue(2);
     q1.enqueue(3);
     q1.enqueue(4);
     q1.enqueue(5);
     q1.printList();
     LinkedListQueue q2 = new LinkedListQueue();
     q2.enqueue(6);
     q2.enqueue(7);
     q2.enqueue(8);
     q2.enqueue(9);
     q2.printList();     
}
public static LinkedListQueue merge(LinkedListQueue q1, LinkedListQueue q2){
    LinkedListQueue q3 = new LinkedListQueue();
    LinkedListQueue merged = LinkedListQueue.merge(q1,q2);
}

}
```

Here is what I have put in my LinkedList class

```
    public static LinkedListQueue merge(LinkedListQueue q1, LinkedListQueue q2) {
    if (q1 == null) {
        return (q2);
    } else if (q2 == null) {
        return (q1);
    }
    LinkedListQueue merge = new LinkedListQueue();
    merge.enqueue(q1);
    merge.enqueue(q2);
    return merge;
}
```

And here is what I have put in my Main. Which now prints the two queues but prints out the node location and not what prints out when I call the other queues.

```
    LinkedListQueue q3 = new LinkedListQueue();
q3 = LinkedListQueue.merge(q1,q2);
q3.printList();
```

Comment: you need to be more specific about your issue

Comment: what problem  your are facing?

Comment: Well, right now the problem is that the merge method is absent. Did you at least try to write it?

Comment: While trying to merge these two queues the merge method is coming up as symbol not found.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this snippet of code:

```
public static LinkedListQueue merge(LinkedListQueue q1, LinkedListQueue q2){
    LinkedListQueue q3 = new LinkedListQueue();
    LinkedListQueue merged = LinkedListQueue.merge(q1,q2); //problematic line
}
```

Specifically the part `LinkedListQueue.merge(q1,q2);`. This syntax is saying to call the static method `merge` defined *in the class `LinkedListQueue`*. However, looking in your code for `LinkedListQueue`, I don't see a `static` `merge` method defined.

The way your code is written, it is expecting something like:

```
public class LinkedListQueue<E> implements Queue<E>{
    public static LinkedListQueue<E> merge(LinkedListQueue<E> q1, LinkedListQueue<E> q2){
        //definition here
    }

    //more class code
}
```

See here for [more about static methods](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program).

Comment: I have just ammended what i posted and have added in a static method

Comment: @user4935102 Your adjustment doesn't appear to properly use the generic types (`<E>`s). Try adjusting that. *gotta run, sorry.